# Redis AUTH with random password

Tags: django, ubuntu, redis, centos

I have 2 servers running redis, one was delivered to me out of the box in a VM, an old Ubuntu (12.04) with redis 2.2.12, the new one I configure it myself with redis 2.8.19, a centos 7. I have a django app with redis that fails in the centos server with `Client sent AUTH, but no password is set`, if I go to the redis-cli, and I use `AUTH <anything>` it response me with the same error, which is ok, however, in the ubuntu server if I do the same thing with any random password, it says `OK`. How is this possible?

Neither of the server is configured for authentication in the redis.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

From redis.conf:

```
# Require clients to issue AUTH <PASSWORD> before processing any other
# commands.  This might be useful in environments in which you do not trust
# others with access to the host running redis-server.
#
# This should stay commented out for backward compatibility and because most
# people do not need auth (e.g. they run their own servers).
#
# Warning: since Redis is pretty fast an outside user can try up to
# 150k passwords per second against a good box. This means that you should
# use a very strong password otherwise it will be very easy to break.
#
# requirepass foobared
```

So, unless you set `requirepass`, redis will accept any command without authentication.

Comment: I know that. But both servers have the same configuration regarding requirepass (that is, neither has it active) and still Ubuntu allows me to use the `AUTH randompassword` command with an OK response and CentOS gives me an error when trying to do the same.

Comment: Yeah I did. I even reboot the system. Stop the server, change the configuration (add password), etc.

Comment: Next thing to check is the right configuration file, i use ubuntu, and the configuration is at `/etc/redis/6379.conf`, i think that depends on how you've installed it.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot find another configuration file on the ubuntu server :/

Comment: Run redis-cli an execute: `config GET requirepass;`